# How to define multiple values in routes from a view template in Play 2

Tags: scala, routes, playframework-2.0

In my Play 2.4.4 project I have a view template that i want to return 2 values, a Long and a String.

I have a button that calls the appropriate method in my controller:

```
<p>
  <a href="@controllers.routes.Orders.rollbackStatus(order.id, order.status.toString)" 
     class="btn">@Messages("orders.rollback")</a>
</p>
```

The method in my controller calls a function on a model object:

```
def rollbackStatus(id: Long, status: String) = Action {
  Order.demoteStatus(id, status)
  Redirect(routes.Orders.list())
}
```

In my routes file I have defined the HTTP method, URI and controller method:

```
GET  /orders/:id/:status  controllers.Orders.rollbackStatus(id: Long, status: String)
```

When I press the button however i get the following message:

> BAD REQUEST
>   For request 'GET /orders/3,PLACED' [Cannot parse parameter id as Long: For input string: "3,PLACED"]

I have managed to pass single values in the same way successfully.

Here is the rest of the routes defined for /orders:

```
GET /orders             controllers.Orders.list
GET /orders/pickorder   controllers.Orders.getOrder
GET /orders/:id         controllers.Orders.show(id: Long)
GET /orders/:id/:status controllers.Orders.rollbackStatus(id: Long, status: String)
```

Comment: Show us your ALL `GET /orders/...` routes in the order of appearance

Comment: It seems `GET /orders/3,PLACED` is missing a `/`

Comment: I have added all my routes for GET /orders/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer, When you specify the first parameter you use '/:' to define the name of the parameter.

All subsequent parameters are separated with just '/'.

I believe this is because the ':' specifies the start of the arguments however this is not clear from the Play documentation

Here is the corrected routes listing, all other code is unchanged from the code provided in the question:

```
GET /orders             controllers.Orders.list
GET /orders/pickorder   controllers.Orders.getOrder
GET /orders/:id         controllers.Orders.show(id: Long)
GET /orders/:id/status controllers.Orders.rollbackStatus(id: Long, status: String)
```